# How God has eyes when there was no light?

Tags: bible, existence-of-god

In the beginning of the bible it is said that God created man in his image and likeness. That means by the way that god had eyes. That he had eyes from eternity on is also obvious because he made light and then immediately sow it. But why did he posses eyes when they were useless before creation of light. Of course Darwinism has not that kind of question to ask. Does it prove that bible is not true? I hope of logical answers and not in kind of believers answers.

Comment: God is Spirit and not flesh.  He has no fleshly organs such as eyes.  Therefore the image of God in which humanity was made does not include our physicality.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259). I would also recommend reading the [Help Center's](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) sections on asking and answering questions.

Comment: "That means by the way that god had eyes," no, it doesn't. There is much debate over what "the image of God" means; that it refers to **physical** form is only one *possible* meaning. Personally, I believe "likeness" refers to *mind*, not body. This particularly makes sense when you consider that most features of the human *body* can be found in other animals, but the human *mind* is unique.

Comment: I usually try my best with new contributors but I think you really ought to be thoroughly ashamed of your ignorance in spiritual matters. -1.

Comment: Mercury, please be polite and respectful in your comments. Also see our [**acceptable comments policy for Christianity Stack Exchange**](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7399/acceptable-comments-policy-for-christianity-stack-exchange).

Answer (score 2):

A logical answer presupposes that the question itself is impeccable. Here, the question has been framed with the assumption that we see things with the eye. How  the assumption  stands logics, is to be discussed first. Now, all of us have dreams in sleep when the eyes are shut, and there is hardly any light around. Sometimes the dreams are so clear and scary that we shout ! The fact is that we perceive things with the brain which has billions of neurons working round the clock. True, the retina has 130 million nerve cells which collect information on sight through the help of light falling on the eye-lenses , and pass it on to the brain. It is ultimately the brain which processes those inputs. Sometimes we fail in seeing a friend coming on our way, even if our eyes are open and it is daytime !And there are instances when different persons perceive the  same sight differently. It is because each person's  brain works in a unique manner.  The development of eyes and the astounding equation they have with the brain, even in the simplest form of animals, defy explanation. There definitely is an Intelligent Design behind Creation .The human embryo and fetus do not see any light during the first nine months .  Still, the baby is born with perfect eyes, rather than being uncertain in the womb whether  it will see the light of the day, or not ! Light, for that matter, is an exception, and not a rule. Genesis says that God created light , and does not speak of God having created darkness !  Only a limited area of the universe taken in entirety, gets the advantage of light. This is borne out of the fact that the average temperature of the universe is just above Absolute Zero ! Even the earth is not privileged to have light in all its parts, for instance the deepest parts of the ocean. There are living beings with eyes ,in such areas. Why go to the ocean , the bat does possess eyes even though it does not  see with them ! In sum, it is safe to say that we do not have eyes because there is light in the universe;rather, there is light because we have eyes. If you apply the same principle to God, assuming that He has a fully human form, the logical  answer to the question comes out.As clear as daylight !

Answer (score 1):

The thing with this kind of questions is that you begin with some assumptions and interpretations that fit your thinking, but may not fit the thinking of those you ask the question.

First of all, it looks like you read the Bible as some kind of historical scientific report of the first days of creation. I know that is an interpretation used by some protestant sections of christianity, it definitely isn't the only interpretation. The Catholic Church for example, globally not exactly a small section of christianity, accepts evolution theory up to a high degree and therefore accepts that the first chapters of Genesis are not a scientific report of the facts of creation.

Second, you clearly assume that the words "image and likeness" are to be interpreted as physical. Any christian should be able to tell you that the image of God as some old man on a cloud, is a nice picture for children, but is really not a real christian way of seeing God. As God is spirit, "image and likeness" can mean a lot, but not a physical likeness.

Third you ask a question and then change the wording into an argument against the truthiness of the Bible. That just isn't very fair communicating.

So, does the fact that people have eyes AND people are, according to the Bible, created in Gods image and likeness, proof that the Bible isn't true? No. It may proof though, that you should study a bit more on the use of language, literature, and the meaning of ancient texts.

Comment: Great answer here regarding the point about Genesis not being a scientific report about the first days of creation. I'm curious what you mean by "imago dei" not meaning a physical likeness though. It seems right to me that "image and likeness" implies we both look like God and have some similarities with him in nature.

Comment: The thing here is that God is spirit, not flesh. Only when the Son took "human form"or as the creed says: "incarnatus est de Spiritu Sancto ex Maria Virgine: et homo factus est." God was not only spirit. But Jesus is God AND man, nog a mangod or something like that. So the thin remains, the imago dei does not and cannot mean physical form, I think.

Comment: I don't think there are any assumptions in the question. I rest on the Bible as the only truth. If you mean that a scientific report is true you are right about item 1. If the bible is not a scientific report it is simply not true. But a scientific report must also be logical. Which can not be said about Bible in this case. These catholics who accept Evolution just confirm the bible is not true. About item 2 look at my remark on MikeBorden and Mattew. On item 3 you are right but I can not ask two separate questions.

Comment: The question is based on Bible as the Holy truth. There no assumptions just Bible and logic. On point 1. If the bible is true it must be regarded as a report. 2. See my answer to Mike and Mattew. 3. You are right but how to ask two connected separated questions?

Comment: I am very sorry you have so many assumptions you don’t recognise yourself. This makes communication really hard. And, for me, not interesting.

Comment: @ABMK you interpret the bible just like you wish. No it says in plain text same image. Period. Other interpretations are wishful thinking. It is not based on logic but twisting of facts. So not what is expected at all. Just look there is the Holy Trinity. Are they all Spirits? Answer for yourself!

Comment: I know that is what you think, and I don’t mind.

Comment: Mercury, please understand that **everyone** interprets the Bible. It's a written document, so we have to move from the written words to the meaning of those words. You too are interpreting the Bible. In the OP you refer to God creating man in his own image and likeness (words in the Bible), then you said "this means that God has eyes" (your interpretation of the words in the Bible). The word "eyes" doesn't appear in the text at that point. I'm not saying you're wrong; I'm just asking you to see interpretation is impossible to avoid, and listening to other interpretations is how we learn.